# SQL server varchar.toArray() or string.toArray() method

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert my string data to array in sql server.
I tried it like below.

```
SELECT '223456789' AS SerialOriginalCode
-- SerialOriginalCode 223456789
DECLARE @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion TABLE(ID INT, SerialOriginalCode INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 4),
(5, 5),
(6, 6),
(7, 7),
(8, 8),
(9, 9);
SELECT * FROM @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion
```

But it is manual way, it is not the way of programmatic convertion as it needs me to key in every insert value for each line.

Could someone please suggest me more elegent way?

Comment: i would recommend you do this on the application side. databases are not optimized for such recursive procedural tasks.

Comment: I dont think SQL Server supports any of those two method: `varchar.toArray() or string.toArray() method`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InputText AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '223456789'
DECLARE @Pos Int = 1
DECLARE @End Int
DECLARE @TextLength Int = DATALENGTH(@InputText)

DECLARE @Array TABLE 
(
  TokenID Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Match Varchar(MAX)
)

-- Exit function if no text is passed in.
IF @TextLength <> 0 
  BEGIN
    WHILE @Pos <= @TextLength BEGIN
      INSERT @Array (Match) VALUES (SUBSTRING(@InputText,@Pos,1))
      SET @Pos = @Pos + 1
    END
  END

SELECT * FROM @Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `INSERT` using `number` from `master..spt_values`

```
SELECT '223456789' AS SerialOriginalCode
-- SerialOriginalCode 223456789
DECLARE @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion TABLE(ID INT, SerialOriginalCode INT);

INSERT INTO @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion
SELECT number + 1, SUBSTRING(t.SerialOriginalCode, sv.number + 1, 1) 
FROM (SELECT '223456789' AS SerialOriginalCode) t
INNER JOIN master..spt_values sv ON sv.number < LEN(t.SerialOriginalCode)
WHERE sv.[type] = 'P'


SELECT * FROM @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion
```

**Output:**

```
ID  SerialOriginalCode
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you do this in your application. SQL is optimised for Set based operations and does not handle recursive procedural tasks like like these.

If you want to do this in SQL, you can find the `LEN` of your string and then recursively find the next character. Something like this

**Query**

```
DECLARE @SerialOriginalCode VARCHAR(20) = '223456789'

DECLARE @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion TABLE(ID INT, SerialOriginalCode INT);

DECLARE @len INT = LEN(@SerialOriginalCode)
;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT 1 as ID,CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@SerialOriginalCode,1,1)) as CharInt
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID + 1,CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@SerialOriginalCode,ID + 1,1))
FROM CTE WHERE LEN(@SerialOriginalCode) >= ID + 1
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion(ID,SerialOriginalCode)
SELECT * FROM CTE;

SELECT * FROM @tbl_SerialOriginalVerion
```

**Output**

```
ID  SerialOriginalCode
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

Comment: Thank for your help @ughai. It will be more helpful, if you can submit your customized function "TRY_CONVERT"

Comment: Use `CONVERT` instead of `TRY_CONVERT` if you are using any version before SQL Server 2014

Comment: Thank you @ughai for your continuous help

Answer (score 1):

With cte and Apply:

```
Declare @s nvarchar(9) = '223456789'

;with cte as(
select n from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as t(n))
select * from cte
cross apply(select substring(@s, cte.n, 1) as c) ca
```

Output:

```
n   c
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

Or you can do it with tally tables:

```
declare @s varchar(100) = '223456789'

;with t as(select row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn from
          (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1(n) cross join
          (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t2(n))
select substring(@s, rn, 1) from t
where rn <= len(@s)
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/570

Comment: it will only for work for string with exact 9 characters

Comment: those exact 9 characters are enough for my cause @ughai.